# To be AL legal, is Lost Mine of Phandelver Tier 1 or Level 1 only?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league, lost-mine-of-phandelver

Lost Mine of Phadelver (LMoP) says it is an adventure for Level 1 characters. Yet in Adventurers League, Tier 1 adventurers are for characters levels 1–4.

Reddit [has a post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AdventurersLeague/comments/6fsrpz/level_range_for_phandelver/) where individuals take both sides with one side stating it is a Tier 1 adventure and another posting that LMoP is an exception to the Tier 1 rules because it is a hardcover.

To be AL legal, is LMoP only for Level 1 characters? (And is that true no matter when they join the adventure?) Or is LMoP a Tier 1 adventure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Content Catalog

The [D&D Adventurers League Player's Pack](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack) includes a "Content Catalog", that details all the available adventure sources and what the appropriate level band is. The content catalog is the authoritative document.

As of v7.03a, "Lost Mine of Phandelver" (otherwise known as DDHC-LMOP) has a level band of 1-4. Phandelver being classified as a "hardcover" (that's what DDHC means) indicates that any character within the level range can start the content, but are not kicked out if they breach the listed range<sup>1</sup>. A character outside the listed range for a hardcover can't start it, but can finish one they started while in-range.

### Other Introductory Material

The introductory modules (which group five one-hour mini modules together) are generally the only modules with a restricted level band that doesn't match a tier. In seasons one through five, they were restricted to L1 and L2. Season 6 was handled a little differently - a slice of the HC instead of mini-modules. In fact, the Season Six hardcover itself, Yawning Portal, is a bit of an aberration, but the content catalog details the differences. Season 7's mini-modules are full Tier 1 (L1 through L4).

<sup>1</sup><sub>In DDAL play, it's possible to play modules while still involved in an on-going hardcover group, leveling up at a different time than other players in the same hardcover group might.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For AL, it is 1-4 (Tier 1). Therefore you can play it in AL with a more powerful character than the ones the adventure was written for. Since AL has Tiers that are not limited by specific levels.

This is an oddity of the AL system.